# SSE4.1 intrinsics compilation error on Mac

Tags: gcc, sse, intrinsics

I'm having some trouble using SSE4.1 intrinsics on hardware that (I think) supports it.
Can anyone tell me if I've missed something?

Building the following code on a MacBookPro5,4 (Penryn):

```
>g++ -msse sse4.cpp -S -o sse4.asm

#include <stdio.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

int main ()
{
    __m128 a, b;
    const int mask = 0x55;

    a.m128_f32[0] = 1.5;
    a.m128_f32[1] = 10.25;
    a.m128_f32[2] = -11.0625;
    a.m128_f32[3] = 81.0;
    b.m128_f32[0] = -1.5;
    b.m128_f32[1] = 3.125;
    b.m128_f32[2] = -50.5;
    b.m128_f32[3] = 100.0;

    __m128 res = _mm_dp_ps(a, b, mask);

    printf_s("Original a: %f\t%f\t%f\t%f\nOriginal b: %f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",
                a.m128_f32[0], a.m128_f32[1], a.m128_f32[2], a.m128_f32[3],
                b.m128_f32[0], b.m128_f32[1], b.m128_f32[2], b.m128_f32[3]);
    printf_s("Result res: %f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",
                res.m128_f32[0], res.m128_f32[1], res.m128_f32[2], res.m128_f32[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Generates the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/smmintrin.h:35:3: error: #error "SSE4.1 instruction set not enabled"
```

Comment: Whether your hardware supports SSE4.1 it is irrelevant. Even if it doesn't, the compiler should still be able to generate code for it. Or if the compiler can't generate code for it, the fact that you have the hardware again does not help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change:

`g++ -msse sse4.cpp -S -o sse4.asm`

to:

`g++ -msse4.1 sse4.cpp -S -o sse4.asm`

Comment: Yup. Note there were other errors using the m128_f32[] accessor which appears to be Microsoft specific.

Comment: @Justicle: Yes - just use the `_mm_set_XXX` macros to initialise SIMD data types.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `g++ -msse4.1` ?